# How to display dates as a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of dates.

For example:

```
[Date {Thu Jul 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, null, Date {Sat Jul 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, null, Date {Mon Jul 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, Date {Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, Date {Wed Jul 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}]
```

Seven date after another. Null means no active date.

I would view as:

```
21.07 ; 23.07 ; 25.07 - 27.07
```

Another example:

```
[Date {Thu Jul 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, Date {Fri Jul 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, null, Date {Sun Jul 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, null, Date {Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}, Date {Wed Jul 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200}]
```

Seven date after another. Null means no active date.

As:

```
21.07 - 22.07 ; 24.07 ; 26-07 - 26-07
```

Thank you for your help.

@edit:

```
21.07
null
23.07
null
25.07
26.07
27.07

21.07 ; 23.07 ; 25.07 - 27.07


21.07
null
23.07
null
25.07
null
27.07

21.07 ; 23.07 ; 25.07 ; 27.07


21.07
null
23.07
24.07
25.07
null
null

21.07 ; 23.07 - 25.07


21.07
22.07
23.07
24.07
25.07
null
27.07

21.07 - 25.07 ; 27.07
```

Comment: your array isUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: If your array is like this var arr = ['Thu Jul 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200', null,'Sat Jul 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200', null,'Mon Jul 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200','Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200','Wed Jul 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200'] then it will be solvable

Comment: This is not a real array, only a sketch. But how can I create a string based on a real array (this, as you wrote)?

Comment: So please write the code where you creating array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your list is always made of consecutive days, separated by one (or several) *null*s, this should do what you're expecting:

```js
var input = [
  new Date('Thu Jul 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200'),
  null,
  new Date('Sat Jul 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200'),
  null,
  new Date('Mon Jul 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200'),
  new Date('Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200'),
  new Date('Wed Jul 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200')
];

function formatDay(d) {
  return ('0' + d.getDate()).substr(-2, 2) + '.' +
         ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2, 2);
}

var result = [], end, start = null;

input.forEach(function(v, n) {
  v && (end = v);
  !start && (start = v);
  
  if(start && (!v || n == input.length - 1)) {
    result.push(formatDay(start) + (end == start ? '' : ' - ' + formatDay(end)));
    start = null;
  }
});
result = result.join(' ; ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To create string based of date array

```
<script>
var array = [];
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        var date = new Date();
        array.push(date);
    }

</script> 

<script>
    arr = ['Thu Jul 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200', null,'Sat Jul 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200', null,'Mon Jul 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200','Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200','Wed Jul 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200'];


    var newarray = "";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        if(arr[i] !=null){
        var date = new Date(arr[i]);
        newarray += (date.getDate()+'.'+date.getMonth()+';');
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The array is OK. I do not need a new array only string. The string should look like: "21.07 ; 23.07 ; 25.07 - 27.07" (exactly with semicolons between days and dashes between the day side by side).

Comment: Please check now it i what you required

Comment: It's string, very good, but the date next to each other not as a range. "21.07 ; 23.07 ; 25.07 - 27.07" <-- 26.07 is missing because it is between 25.07 and 27.07 (and a dash, not a semicolon).

Comment: Please tell me one thing that how you are deciding between which date you want dash or not..if you you will tell  i will apply the  logic